# Insert line or update line if it matches a condition. With repeated terms, not unique

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, insert, case

Note: It is not possible to use ON CONFLICT, the fields are not unique: serie_name and season are repeated several times.

I need to update the number of episodes of a season in a series. I have a table with 3000 rows, which I need to check one by one, if the record does not exist, I will insert a new row, if it already exists, update the row.
I have this example table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "series_test" (
    "id_key"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "serie_name"    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "season"    INTEGER,
    "episode_dub"   INTEGER,
    "episode_leg"   INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES ('id_key','serie_name','season','episode_dub','episode_leg');
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (2,'1 Contra Todos',1,8,0);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (2,'1 Contra Todos',2,8,0);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (2,'1 Contra Todos',3,8,0);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (2,'1 Contra Todos',4,8,0);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (175,'Band Of Brothers',1,10,10);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (175,'Band Of Brothers',2,0,4);
INSERT INTO "series_test" VALUES (175,'Band Of Brothers',3,0,13);
COMMIT;
```

I need to insert a line, but if the field data already exists in 'serie_name' and the field 'season', the command just updates the record.
If the condition not exists, insert ... Otherwise update the data

it would be logic like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM series_test WHERE serie_name='Band Of Brothers' AND season=3) 
    UPDATE series_test SET episode_dub=5 AND episode_leg=15 WHERE serie_name='Band Of Brothers' AND season=3
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO series_test (serie_name, season, episode_dub, episode_leg) VALUES ('Band Of Brothers', 3, 5, 15)
```

What would be the most optimized way to do this?

---

Complement:

I don't know what the best way to do this would be if using just sql. Or using python + sql.

I do web scraping via python to get the latest episode data for the series in each season. and I would need to enter that data or update it.

update old data, increased the number of episodes of a season

```
{'id_key': 175, 'serie_name': 'Band Of Brothers', 'season': 3, 'episode_dub': 5, 'episode_leg': 15}
```

insert a new season of a series with its episodes:

```
{'id_key': 175, 'serie_name': 'Band Of Brothers','season': 4,' episode_dub': 1, 'episode_leg': 3}
```

Comment: You have no examples of duplicates series/season in the sample data.  I would suggest that you update the questin.

Comment: is this tagged correctly Is this SQL or python?

Comment: I added an complement to the question

Comment: Maybe try two set based operations - Update Join and "Insert where not exists sub query". You have 3000 records in table A to match against table B, updating table B with table A. It sounds like you are planning on iterating through table A to and updating row by row. Try the two set operations above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a composite `UNIQUE` constraint for the columns `serie_name` and `season`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS series_test (
    id_key INTEGER NOT NULL,
    serie_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    season INTEGER,
    episode_dub INTEGER,
    episode_leg INTEGER,
    UNIQUE(serie_name, season)
);
```

Now you can use `ON CONFLICT`:

```
INSERT INTO series_test (id_key, serie_name, season, episode_dub, episode_leg) VALUES 
  (175, 'Band Of Brothers', 3, 5, 15)
ON CONFLICT(serie_name, season) DO UPDATE
SET episode_dub = EXCLUDED.episode_dub, 
    episode_leg = EXCLUDED.episode_leg
```

Note that you must provide a value for the column `id_key` also, because it is defined as `NOT NULL`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=624dbde71664ec6658cf3b2ba654d5d2).